# IntelliJ: Is there a shortcut for "peeking declaration"?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
public static final String XYZ = "something"; // line 1
return XYZ;                                   // line 2
```

With cursor on `XYZ` on line 2, I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will bring me to line 1, where `XYZ` is defined.

Is there a way to **temporarily peek** at its declaration? That is, with some particular keys hold down, it goes to line 1, but returns to line 2 when I release?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`View > Quick Definition` when the cursor is on `XYZ` will cause a popup to display with the definition of that constant. Then you can hit `ESC` to dismiss the popup at which point the cursor will still be on `XYZ`.

For example:

[image]

You can see the keyboard short cut for `View > Quick Definition` next to that menu item ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is the `View > Quick Definitions` shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + I`. It works on IntelliJ 2023.x, though I'm not sure for older versions, but it probably does.